# Java applet with usb access in Windows and Linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, applet, usb

We're developing a kind of gadget with usb connection but would not to force our users to install any driver and program in their computers, so... ¿it's possible to develop a java applet that work in linux and windows and have usb access?
(We're java developers but nerver before worked with applets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have chosen a USB API. [This is one option](http://javax-usb.org/). The steps you have to take in order to make it work as an applet are:

- digitally sign the applet - it would require permissions to use the USB API
- put the .jar file of the usb api in a folder on your web server and include it in the `archive` attribute of the applet tag(s). [See my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965537/trying-to-get-a-signed-applet-to-work-in-a-browser-but-fails-miserably/1965614) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app's interface need to be embedded in a web page? If not, you might want to look into [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp), which lets you run Java Applications by clicking on a link in a browser.

Comment: What has this to do with the question asked?

Comment: sucotronic dosn't want his users to install drivers or software for his application.  Either applets or java web start would work fine for that.

Comment: we're also investigating about the option of using JWS, because the size of the applet may be too large :P